# MVC3 move DB fom SQL Server Compact Edition to SQL Server Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

Have a problem here. I'm trying to work with SQL Server Express instead of SQL Server CE. Though my app is already working with SQL Server CE, I need to figure out what changes I need to make. I created a new database connection - it generated me a new *.dbo file. I made few changes in my `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection"
           connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DatabaseExpressContext;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
           xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>      
    </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="SqlClient Data Provider"
    invariant="System.Data.SqlClient"
    description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer"
    type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data,
     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    />
    </DbProviderFactories>
```

But nothing happens.. Nothing works... I'm connecting to my *.dbo file - tables aren't even building.

I couldn't find any useful info about my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *.dbo file? Let's make sure were on the same track here. And do you transform the connection string in debug/release.config?

Comment: Yes, I made changes in my release.config, I'll attach image to make clear: [Image](http://i45.tinypic.com/117xu09.jpg)

Comment: OK, so that's your Обозреватель серверов (server explorer :) ) which shows that the database exists and is attached to your sqlexpress instance. Was it generated by your code?

Comment: Nope, I created it manually. In server explorer - Created new sql server database. I made changes in my application properties, made "Pull data from existing database" - "DataSource=|AppData|MyDB.mdf" - still no changes... Don't know what to do...

Comment: I had the impression that you worked code-first, so you should run your code and have the new database created by your context.

Comment: I had that impression to :). You're right I'm working with code-first approach. Is it normal I'm having empty tables in server explorer (When I open SQL express database), have no database files in my App_Data folder? I have nothing... No changes.

Comment: The database is hosted by your local sql express server. The physical location of the file does not matter, the connection string is all you need. Maybe you should delete the database and let your code create it according to the connection string.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I wish I could increase your rating somehow :)